# To Add Minimize /Maximize button to JDialog orJPanel

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jdialog

Is it possible to add maximize/minimize button to the JDialog? if not then can we add these buttons to JPanel?

I have a JPanel and inside that panel there is a JDialog.I want to add a minimize/maximize button such that when that button is clicked JDialog and the components under JDialog get adjusted according to the JPanel.
like when i click maximize then jpanel should get enlarged and components inside that panel(JDialog) also get enlarged and vice versa for minimize button.
The solution I got from here is for JPanel inside a JFrame. But my JPanel is standalone only.

Comment: do u need something like [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/internalframe.html) ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is it possible to add maximize/minimize button to the JDialog?

- not, don't do that, (even there are a few dirty hacks) you can to `JDialog.setUndecorated` and add required Windows decoration back, notice resources for JDialog/JWindow came from Native OS, valid for `SystemLookAndFeel` only and could be `CrossPlatfor`m sensitive

> if not then can we add these buttons to JPanel?

- yes, but you can to use `JOptionPane` and with modified contents, there you can put any `JComponents` and/with returns value too

Comment: thanx. I am trying using JOptionPane. :)

Comment: Now I changed my GUI as there is a frame and inside that frame there are panels. On clicking the maximize button the window is getting maximized but the panels inside the windows are not ajusting accordingly.they are not getting maximize and their positions are also changing.please help.

Comment: It is mind boggling. I have a sizable window and I cannot maximize it with a simple click only after tons of programming. That was someone's brainded decision a long time ago. What has modality do with maximization? Why did they link them? Sigh. Grr. LOL.

Comment: @mKorbel `JOptionPane` is not Modalless.

Answer (score 3):

`JDialog`: No.

`JPanel`: Yes, simply use `JButtons` setting the `JFrame#setMaximizedState` value, in the listeners, but not on `JDialog`.