# How to check JDialog state

Tags: java, swing, state, jdialog, windowlistener

I have a JDialog and I'd like to check whether its state is maximized, minimized or normal.
How can I do that?

I have tried:

```
private JDialog dialog = new JDialog();
dialog.addWindowStateListener(new WindowStateListener() { 
        @Override
        public void windowStateChanged(WindowEvent e) {  
                if(e.getNewState()==JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH){ 
                        System.out.println(" state MAXIMIZED_BOTH");
                        dialog.repaint();
                }
        }
    });
```

but it doesn't work of course.

Thanks

Comment: you are looking for `addComponentListener` perhaps

Comment: addWindowStateListener works fine, I'm just looking for a way to check the JDialog state

Answer (score 0):

A JDialog does not show the minimize/maximize buttons. If you look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13718054/to-add-minimize-maximize-button-to-jdialog-orjpanel), someone asked if you could add those buttons to a JDialog and it is discouraged. It looks like if you add a WindowStateListener to a JDialog, it never gets triggered.

Comment: thanks, but my jdialog does have those buttons (you can check it out here http://nadeausoftware.com/node/91 how to do that), now I need a way to check their state