# JDialog with Max/Min Button?

Tags: java, swing, jdialog, modality

Is there anyway I can add a `JPanel` in a Modal-less `JDialog` that also has Max/Min/Close buttons? Even when I do something like this, it does not show max/min button.

```
JFrame f1 = new JFrame("Book 1 (parent frame)");
            JDialog myDialog = new JDialog(f1);
            myDialog.setVisible(true);
```

I am looking to have a window like this which is modalless and have max/min buttons

[image]

Update: In [these examples](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/modality.html) I can see modalless dialogs with max/min button but can't figure out why are they not working for me

Comment: @mKorbel What do you mean?

Comment: @mKorbel Actually I want to add `JPanel` in Dialog and show max/min button. I tried this but it did not work either. MY main motive is to show JPanel based stuff in a Modalless Dialog

Comment: JFrame has 3buttons(can be visible in TaskBar), JDialog only one, JWindow is without button, this is standard for windowing conceptand valid for most of Native OS's

Comment: for better help sooner post an SSCCE/MCVE, short, runnable, compilable

Comment: @Volatil3, why don't you use [JInternalFrame](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JInternalFrame.html) ? Also see how to [use it](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/internalframe.html)

Comment: @Arvind I need a window like this:

http://www.docear.org/wp-content/uploads/2012/08/Docear4Word-Add-BibTeX-reference-in-Microsoft-Word.png

Comment: @mKorbel Refer to this image(http://www.docear.org/wp-content/uploads/2012/08/Docear4Word-Add-BibTeX-reference-in-Microsoft-Word.png)

I tried to achieve by adding `JPanel` in `JDialog`, it did not work for me.

Comment: @mKorbel So are you saying that I don't need to put `JFrame` in a `JDialog` and can show it modalless?

Comment: A complete example is shown [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11832979/230513); @mKorbel is [correct](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13718147/230513): `JDialog` should not be minimized.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok Finally this worked for me. It might be helpful for other readers.

```
JFrame.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(true);
            JFrame f = new JFrame();
            f.setResizable(false);
            JPanel p = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
            JButton btn = new JButton("Exit");
            p.add(btn,new GridBagConstraints());
            f.getContentPane().add(p);
            f.setSize(400,300);
            f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            f.setVisible(true);
```

I got impression that I need to put things in `JDialog` anyway while same could be achieved by using `JFrame`

Answer (score 0):

The way I understand your question, you're trying to give a JPanel (which is inside a nonmodal window) windowing options.

A JPanel probably wouldn't work for this; instead, you should use a [JInternalFrame](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/internalframe.html), which allows you to accomplish this. It's a component which goes inside a window and which itself can be minimized, maximized, and dragged around.