# How to do Minimize Functionality JTextArea in window?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jdialog

We have a `JFrame` on which there is a button which is responsible for opening another window that has a `JTextArea`.

We want to provide the minimize functionality for that text area.

```
final JTextArea jta = new JTextArea();
final JDialog dialog = new JDialog();
```

I already set the minimize functionality using frame but it is not working.

```
jframe.setState(Frame.ICONIFIED);
```

Also We provide `JDialog` to set it visible:

```
dialog.setVisible(true);
```

May I know what to do for this particular type of scenario?

==========================================================

## UPDATED CODE

```
 final JTextArea jta = new JTextArea();
        final JDialog dialog = new JDialog();
        JButton openTextMode = new JButton();
        JOptionPane jOptionPane = new JOptionPane();

        openTextMode.setText("Open Text Mode");

        openTextMode.setFocusable(false);
        setUndecorated(false);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.HIDE_ON_CLOSE);
        openTextMode.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                JavaLogger.debug("default", "You clicked on Open Text Mode Button");
                jta.setBounds(150, 200, 500, 400);
                jta.setText(getTerminalContent());

                    dialog.setVisible(true);

            }


         });

        dialog.setModal(false);
        dialog.setBounds(150, 200, 500, 400);
        dialog.add(jta);
```

Comment: Is that `JTextArea` inside the `JDialog`? Please post a [mcve].

Comment: Hi @PrasadKarunagoda yes JTextArea is inside the JDialog only .... I updated the Example

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13718054/to-add-minimize-maximize-button-to-jdialog-orjpanel